# How to add icons which aren't in navbar to hamburger menu for mobile version?

Tags: html, responsive, hamburger-menu

I have navbar with menu, which changed to hamburger menu on mobile version. Also, I have two icons for language, which aren't in navbar, but I need them in hamburger menu.
Option to put language icons in  doesn't work because I need them to the right, and then all menu list change the place

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-inverse" data-toggle="affix" id="navbar-spy" style="border:0px; border-radius:0px">
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="zastave" align="right">
        <a href="#"><img src="slike/srb.png" alt=""></a>
        <a href="ENG/index.html"><img src="slike/eng.png" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <span> <a href="#pocetni"><img  class="logo_nav pull-xs-left" src="slike/logo.png"></a></span>

    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav p-t-1">
          <li><a href="#MENI">MENI</a></li>
          <li><a href="#ENTERIJER">ENTERIJER</a></li>
          <li><a href="#CENOVNIK">CENOVNIK</a></li>
          <li><a href="#REZERVACIJA">REZERVACIJA</a></li>
          <li><a href="#KONTAKT">KONTAKT</a></li>
          <!--<li><a href="#KETERING">KETERING</a></li>-->
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Add a class to the items you don't want to show in the normal menu like: `mobile-only`, then in CSS you can just hide them on screen size using `display:none`. As you've got the hamburger menu already implemented, I guess you know how to use CSS media queries? If not, give a shout so we can explain how to use them.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer! I know to use media queries. So, I will have on two place language icons, and in normal size, one will be hidden, for mobile another, right?

Comment: That would be an option. But could you please show a design or indication how you would like to position them? Then I can see if it's possible to include them only once in your code. That would be nicer then adding them twice and hiding one. I was in the supposition that you would only include them once but only show them on mobile devices.

Comment: Sure. This is how it looks like https://snag.gy/V2omFq.jpg and I need when is mobile version, to be in hamburger menu. When I put it in ul list, everything change their place

Comment: Hmm. The quick fix would be what I suggested above. Another fix would be much better by positioning it all by using media queries. I've no time to work that out for you right now. Maybe tonight I can (or some other users who read this).

Some quick information how you would do that: make one div where everything is in. On the desktop version you'll float it left (just like you did), and a width of the container div of 100%. If you switch to mobile use Media Queries to make the div's smaller and stop floating the LI items (and the flags) to get them under each other.

Comment: Thanks a lot anyway! I will try in this way, hope it will work...

Comment: Let me know if you did get a solution? :) Else I'll maybe, if I have some time later today/this week, make you an example how I would fix it.

Comment: Yes, I am! :) It probably isn't the best way, but it works. Now, it looks :    <div class="zastave hidden-xs visible-sm visible-md visible-lg visible-xl" align="right">
            <a href="../index.html"><img src="slike/srb.png" alt=""></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="slike/eng.png" alt=""></a>                 </div> and <li class="visible-xs">
    <a class="m" href="../index.html"><img src="slike/srb.png" alt=""></a>
    <a class="m" href="#.html"><img src="slike/eng.png" alt=""></a>
     </li> under hamburger. Thanks :)

Comment: Awesome! Have fun coding. :)